# How to create a newline in Watson dialog xml?

Tags: xml, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

If I have something like the following in watson dialog xml:

```
        <output id="output_2508575">
            <prompt selectionType="SEQUENTIAL">
                <item>Your options are: &#xa;
                      option1,&#xa;
                      option2,&#xa;
                      option3
                </item>
            </prompt>
        </output>
```

I get "Your options are: option1,option2,option3" without any newlines.

How do I create a newline?  In addition to the above example I've also tried
 \n 
<br> 
<br /> 
&lt;br /&gt; 
&lt;br&gt; 
&#xa;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
<item>Your options are:&lt;br&gt;
  option 1,&lt;br&gt;
  option 2,&lt;br&gt;
  option 3&lt;br&gt;
</item>
```